# In TechTalk SpecFlow, how do I abandon a Scenario?

Tags: testing, specflow, cancellation

My scenario reads a file with hundreds of lines. Each line calls an API Service, but the service may not be running. If I get a non-200 response (available inside the 'Then' method), I want to abandon the Scenario & save time. 
How can I tell TechTalk SpecFlow to not carry on with the other tests?

Comment: I would question the approach here. Wouldn't you want to make sure your api service is active and 'warm' before running tests against it?

Comment: @Konzy262 that would make the test script more complicated - and I'm not the one who wrote it. It's quite difficult to follow, as it looks like it's written by an English major rather than a computer programmer, and the mapping to actual code almost but not quite quite different to the method names e.g. something like "If I read the file and call the functional api then verify that the names match what's on the label" but of course those are not the names of the methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a concept like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25645845/specflow-stop-feature-in-case-a-scenario-fails) .

```
       public static FeatureContext _featureContext;

     public binding( FeatureContext featureContext)
            {

                _featureContext = featureContext;
            }

     [Given(@"user login")]
      public void login(){
      // do test
        bool testPassed = //set based on test. true or false
        binding._featureContext.Current["testPass"] = testPassed;
      }
```

Then in  BeforeScenario()

```
    [BeforeScenario(Order = 1)]
    public void BeforeScenario()
     {

       Assert.IsTrue(FeatureContext.Current["testPass"];);

     }
```

Comment: This may be what I'm looking for, but IIRC I tried using the dictionary but it get's reset for each call. I'll have a look again later